# Gazebo dies when openning with PR2 controller

Tags: ros, gazebo, pr2, pr2-controller-manager, pr2-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all:

I was learning arm_navigation, by reading the tutorials. In "Checking a state for validity", I should run :

```
  export ROBOT=sim
  roslaunch pr2_arm_navigation_tutorials pr2_floorobj_world.launch
```

but I couldn't open gazebo successfully. Instead, it terminated and showed some messages as follow:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/scripts/spawner", line 159, in <module>
      if __name__ == '__main__': main()
    File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/scripts/spawner", line 137, in main
resp = load_controller(name)
    File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 430, in __call__
return self.call(*args, **kwds)
    File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 519, in call
      raise ServiceException("transport error completing service call: %s"%(str(e)))
  rospy.service.ServiceException: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
  [WARN] [WallTime: 1332306075.862983] [4.181000] Spawner couldn't reach       pr2_controller_manager to take down controllers.
  [gazebo-2] process has died [pid 32591, exit code -11].
  log files: /home/albert/.ros/log/dd42c886-7312-11e1-bef1-5404a6dc3a5e/gazebo-2*.log
  [default_controllers_spawner-23] process has died [pid 32680, exit code 1].
  log files: /home/albert/.ros/log/dd42c886-7312-11e1-bef1-5404a6dc3a5e/default_controllers_spawner-23*.log
```

I could see pr2 in gazebo for a second and then the process died, and the program was closed immediately

I can run it on my laptop, but get this problem on my PC. My OS is ubuntu 10.10, and I use ros-electric. I'm pretty sure that I've install all the required packages or dependencies.

really appreciate for any help, thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30105/gazebo-dies-when-openning-with-pr2-controller/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-03-21**:
does roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch work for you?

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-03-21**:
No, it stil terminated with the same error. I think it's because this launch file include pr2_gazebo/pr2.launch , which include pr2_controller_configuration_gazebo/pr2_default_controllers.launch

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-03-21**:
Same problem as here, I'd say (and I also found no solution): http://answers.ros.org/question/28253/rosgazebo-crashes-when-spawing-pr2-robot-model  Bug?

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-03-22**:
Actually, this error didn't happen on my computer before.......until one day, I dist-upgrade ros and my Ubuntu. The CPU of my PC is core i5 2450 and GPU is Nvidia GeForce GT 520. I've tried to re-install ros electric and even Ubuntu, but the damage seemed to be irreversible...so weird

**Comment by [Enea Scioni](https://answers.ros.org/users/1546/enea-scioni/) on 2012-03-22**:
Same to me. The problem seems come from when I'm using the discrete GPU (Nvidia GT540M), using bumblebee (optirun command). Without discrete GPU I don't get any problems.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably not an error with the controllers, the error you see is what happens after gazebo segfaults and exits before controllers can be taken down properly.  Can you include more of the console outputs?

Does it work with gdb as posted in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/28253/rosgazebo-crashes-when-spawing-pr2-robot-model)?

On another note, I have seen similar errors when running with nvidia 295.* drivers, the segfault goes away after I downgraded to 285.* drivers.  Be careful when downgrading, from experience, 295.* drivers left bits of kernel modules and libraries in miscellaneous places on my system that ultimately confused my system for a while, make sure to uninstall debs:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-current-updates* nvidia-current*
```

if you are installing the 285.* drivers manually.

more info on the bug:
this is the backtrace I got when I tried 295.20 driver on my oneiric system:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7f51f91c7700 (LWP 30795)]
0x00007f5239dc7c0f in _nv022tls () from /usr/lib/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.295.20
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f5239dc7c0f in _nv022tls () from /usr/lib/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.295.20
#1  0x00007f523ceb4a01 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
#2  0x00007f52475ab5a5 in __libc_fork () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/../fork.c:95
#3  0x00007f52475687ab in _IO_new_proc_open (fp=0x7f522c307b20, command=0x7f522c4a0478 "ret=\"/opt/ros/electric/stacks/arm_navigation/joint_normalization_filters/default_plugins.xml\" && echo $ret", mode=<optimized out>)
    at iopopen.c:191
#4  0x00007f5247568b01 in _IO_new_popen (command=0x7f522c4a0478 "ret=\"/opt/ros/electric/stacks/arm_navigation/joint_normalization_filters/default_plugins.xml\" && echo $ret", mode=0x7f52463ccb51 "r") at iopopen.c:312
#5  0x00007f52463b85df in rospack::Package::direct_flags (this=0x7f522c07f9b0, lang=..., attrib=...) at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-1.6.8/debian/ros-electric-ros/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rospack/rospack.cpp:584
#6  0x00007f52463bf800 in rospack::Package::plugins (this=0x7f522c441d10) at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-1.6.8/debian/ros-electric-ros/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rospack/rospack.cpp:304
#7  0x00007f52463c0062 in rospack::ROSPack::cmd_plugins (this=0x7f51f91c57e0) at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-1.6.8/debian/ros-electric-ros/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rospack/rospack.cpp:1164
#8  0x00007f52463c2fd7 in rospack::ROSPack::run (this=0x7f51f91c57e0, argc=4, argv=0x7f522c513200) at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-1.6.8/debian/ros-electric-ros/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rospack/rospack.cpp:1438
#9  0x00007f52463c3826 in rospack::ROSPack::run (this=0x7f51f91c57e0, cmd=<optimized out>) at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-1.6.8/debian/ros-electric-ros/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rospack/rospack.cpp:1206
#10 0x00007f5248e43f03 in ros::package::command (_cmd=...) at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-1.6.8/debian/ros-electric-ros/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/package.cpp:55
#11 0x00007f5248e44245 in ros::package::command (cmd=<optimized out>, output=...) at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-1.6.8/debian/ros-electric-ros/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/package.cpp:73
#12 0x00007f5248e4478b in ros::package::getPlugins (package=..., attribute=<optimized out>, plugins=...) at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-1.6.8/debian/ros-electric-ros/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/package.cpp:125
#13 0x00007f5248e4537c in ros::package::getPlugins (package=<optimized out>, attribute=<optimized out>, plugins=...) at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-1.6.8/debian/ros-electric-ros/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/package.cpp:113
#14 0x00007f51f6733cae in pluginlib::ClassLoader<filters::FilterBase<double> >::ClassLoader (this=0x7f522c485828, package=..., base_class=..., attrib_name=...)
    at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/pluginlib/include/pluginlib/class_loader_imp.h:51
#15 0x00007f51f6726f0d in FilterChain (data_type=..., this=0x7f522c485828) at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/filters/include/filters/filter_chain.h:53
#16 controller::LaserScannerTrajController::LaserScannerTrajController (this=0x7f522c485670)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-pr2-controllers-1.6.2/debian/ros-electric-pr2-controllers/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_controllers/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/laser_scanner_traj_controller.cpp:47
#17 0x00007f51f67274e8 in controller::LaserScannerTrajControllerNode::LaserScannerTrajControllerNode (this=0x7f522c485560)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-pr2-controllers-1.6.2/debian/ros-electric-pr2-controllers/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_controllers/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/laser_scanner_traj_controller.cpp:399
#18 0x00007f51f6734e3a in Poco::MetaObject<controller::LaserScannerTrajControllerNode, pr2_controller_interface::Controller>::create (this=<optimized out>) at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/pluginlib/include/Poco/MetaObject.h:165
#19 0x00007f52057abc57 in create (className=..., this=0x7f522431b9b8) at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/pluginlib/include/Poco/ClassLoader.h:360
#20 pluginlib::ClassLoader<pr2_controller_interface::Controller>::createClassInstance (this=0x7f522431b950, lookup_name=..., auto_load=<optimized out>) at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/pluginlib/include/pluginlib/class_loader_imp.h:277
#21 0x00007f520578d68f in pr2_controller_manager::ControllerManager::loadController (this=<optimized out>, name=...)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-pr2-mechanism-1.5.4/debian/ros-electric-pr2-mechanism/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/src/controller_manager.cpp:289
#22 0x00007f520578ee02 in pr2_controller_manager::ControllerManager::loadControllerSrv (this=0x7f522e917090, req=..., resp=...)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-pr2-mechanism-1.5.4/debian/ros-electric-pr2-mechanism/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/src/controller_manager.cpp:799
#23 0x00007f52057b4f8b in operator() (a1=<optimized out>, a0=<optimized out>, this=0x7f522430dd98) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#24 call (params=..., cb=...) at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/service_callback_helper.h:142
#25 ros::ServiceCallbackHelperT<ros::ServiceSpec<pr2_mechanism_msgs::LoadControllerRequest_<std::allocator<void> >, pr2_mechanism_msgs::LoadControllerResponse_<std::allocator<void> > > >::call (this=0x7f522430dd90, params=...)
    at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/service_callback_helper.h:200
#26 0x00007f5249bbd232 in ros::ServiceCallback::call (this=0x7f522c53aca0)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-comm-1.6.6/debian/ros-electric-ros-comm/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/service_publication.cpp:123
#27 0x00007f5249bccc59 in ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB (this=0x2355b20, tls=0x62f2120)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-comm-1.6.6/debian/ros-electric-ros-comm/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:381
#28 0x00007f5249bce74b in ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable (this=0x2355b20, timeout=<optimized out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-comm-1.6.6/debian/ros-electric-ros-comm/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:333
#29 0x00007f5249b6b42a in ros::spinOnce () at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-comm-1.6.6/debian/ros-electric-ros-comm/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/init.cpp:518
#30 0x00007f52059e72bf in gazebo::GazeboRosControllerManager::ControllerManagerROSThread (this=0x7f522e9158b0)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-pr2-simulator-1.6.0/debian/ros-electric-pr2-simulator/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_simulator/pr2_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_controller_manager.cpp:509
#31 0x00007f5249280ba9 in thread_proxy () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
#32 0x00007f524a29aefc in start_thread (arg=0x7f51f91c7700) at pthread_create.c:304
#33 0x00007f52475df89d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:112
#34 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

and here is the [discussion thread I found](http://nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=2529198) with a small glut test to reproduce the problem.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-06-24**:
I tried to follow the steps with gdb. But the second method there has a call to roslaunch with just one argument. That doesn't work since it expects a package name. How do I resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much, hsu! Gazebo won't terminate when I install another version of the GPU driver. My graphic card is Nvidia GT520, and the driver was version:295.20. On 3/22 Nvidia launch version:295.33. After I re-install and upgrade to the latest version, I can run pr2 in gazebo successfully. I didn't try version:280.* ,but I hope it works for others who had the same problem.
By the way, this is really a weird problem. I installed version:295.20 before and there's no problem...until I dist-upgrade my ubuntu and ros-electric some day. I hope that I shouldn't do the same procedure next time I upgrade my system. At last, again thank you very much!

---

Originally posted by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) with karma: 301 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-03-22**:
You can find all versions of nvidia drivers here : http://www.geforce.com/drivers/beta-legacy

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Nvidia driver update to .33 also solved the issue I had with getting the pr2 simulator up and running.

---

Originally posted by [ainbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/1866/ainbro/) with karma: 13 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1